# IRkernel dies when running mclapply with dada2

Tags: r, jupyter, mclapply, jupyter-irkernel

I don't know if this issue is dada2 specific or not. I would guess that it is not but I am not able to reproduce it otherwise.

I am trying to use `mclapply` from the `parallel` library inside of a Jupyter notebook with dada2. The parallel job runs, though the moment it finishes the kernel dies and I am unable to restart it. Running the same workflow inside of an R terminal has no issues.

Running it on a small dataset works with no issues:

```
library(dada2)
library(parallel)

derepFs <- mclapply('seqs/test_f.fastq', derepFastq)
derepFs
```

Running the same workflow but with the full dataset (I'm sorry I am not able to provide it here, it is too large, and not public) causes the kernel to die, this makes me think it is a memory issue, runninng it outside of the Jupyter environment has no issues. Running this with `lapply` has no issues. Also attempting to run this on an AWS instance with more memory results in the the same error. The terminal output when the kernel dies is:

```
Error in poll.socket(list(sockets$hb, sockets$shell, sockets$control),  :
  Interrupted system call
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> poll.socket -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Monitoring memory shows it never gets very high ~200MB. So my question is if it is not memory what could it be? I realize it may be difficult to answer this question, though as I said I cannot post the full dataset. R version 3.2.2, Jupyter version 1.0.0, Dada2 version 0.99.8, OSX 10.11.4

Comment: I'd try https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues

Comment: @jaimedash Yes, good suggestion. I debated about that originally, though I typically assume I am doing something completely obviously wrong until proven otherwise SO is often useful for pointing out simple errors/misunderstandings if they are present

Comment: same (assume doing something obviously wrong). +1 for the sanity check.

Comment: but I'd think an issue is warranted any time a workflow that works in R terminal crashes jupyter

Comment: I eventually found an issue on github that addresses this issue, specifically with IRkernel https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/245.